# SOAP server returns unexpected Action

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe, soap1.2

We are trying to implement a client that connects to a server using SOAP.
We are using a *WSDL* file to generate the client class with the svcutil.

So far I have managed to get the communication working so far as to send a message and receive a response. However the framework receiving the command refuse to accept the answer because the client has added some kind of namespace and servicename (I think) to the Action.

I send a command with the SOAP heading *Action*: `/GetMyTransaction` which comes from the *WSDL* file, and to this command the *WSDL* states that the expected *ReplyAction* should be `/GetMyTransactionResponse`.

However in the response the *Action* is set to `urn://foo/bar/:someService:GetMyTransactionResponse`. Now I'm no SOAP export, so I don't know if this actually might be a valid response. It contains the correct *Action* but it also contains other stuff. Also, the generated file is not accepting the different *Action*.

**So my question is**: is there some way to tell the ServiceModel to accept the additional data?

Now there is the possibility to manually edit the generated code and enter the full *Action*, however the same code should support other servers that does respond as expected, so I can't just edit the generated file and insert the extended *Action*. (Unless maybe there is some kind of wildcard that I could add to the *ReplyAction* property in the OperationContractAttribute.